# Using FuncAnimation from the matplotlib library (Python3)

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

Im using FuncAnimation to move points on a scatterplot randomly around. Ive got them moving around but it doesn't look the smoothest. I understand all the parameters within FuncAnimation except for 'frames'. Would someone be able to explain how the 'frames' parameter works? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FuncAnimation` works by calling a graphing function at each frame.  This is specified by the `func` parameter.  You should expect that `func` needs to return different output each time it is called, or else edit the figure each time it is called (otherwise there would be no animation!).  To do this, we make `func` accept an argument (or arguments), which control its behavior on each call.

**The `frames` parameter of `FuncAnimation` specifies the values that are passed to `func` *each frame***.  So, the first frame of the animation is generated by calling `func(frames[0])`, the second by `func(frames[1])`, the *n*th by `func(frames[n])`.

I typically use `frames` to index data stored in other variables.  For example, I will have some data in `x` and `y`, and `frames` is just a series of `int` used to access `x[i]` and `y[i]` each frame.  Here is a simple example of that:

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,9)
ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
x = range(1, 8)
y = range(100, 800, 100)
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']

# f will be values from frames
def update(f):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(0,9)
    ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
    ax.scatter(x[f], y[f], s=30, c=colors[f]) # f is used to access my data

# frames is just integers from 0 to 6, used to index my data and colors
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func=update, interval=500, frames=range(len(x))
ani.save
```

[image]

There are different possible values of `frames`, but they are always used to feed `func`:

- *iterable*: each element is used, once per frame.  If this has a length (e.g. it isn't a generator), there will be as many frames drawn as the length of `frames`.
- *generator*: the `next` value of the generator is used each frame.
- *integer*: the `range()` of that integer is used to created `frames`.  So in my example, I could have just used `frames = len(x)`.
- *`None`* : if you don't specify `frames`, it will just generate successive integers to pass to `func`.  In this case, I believe you need to specify the `save_count` in order to tell the program when to stop.

Also, note that `frames` doesn't have to just a collection of `int` used to subset other data.  [In the `matplotlib` example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/animation_api.html), `frames` is an iterable of the *actual data being plotted*.  This also works.  For the case above, I could have made `frames = zip(x, y, colors)`, and then access the actual data within each call to `func`; but I find this way to be more confusing.